# ALM add-in error while trying to map excel (2013) fields with ALM fields

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2013, alm

I am trying to upload test cases excel sheet to HP ALM. Below are the steps i followed to upload the sheet -
Login and Auhtentication done successfully . When I click on Mapping and --> Tests it throwing me below error.

I have double checked the (ALM) URL and is correct.

Please Correct me if i am wrong anywhere

**MS office version - 2013**

**ALM Add in - 12.53.94**

Downloaded from - https://hpln.hpe.com/contentoffering/microsoft-excel-add

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check the ALM OTA Client version you're running by logging in with your browser and then click Help>About HP Application Lifecycle Management Software.

You most likely have an older version of the OTA Client in your HPQC installation and from my experience version 12.53 of the MS Word ALM Add-in isn't compatible with some older versions of the OTA Client on the server.

To fix this I had to remove version 12.53 of the MS Word ALM Add-in via Uninstall from Installed Programs and the download and re-install a version compatible with my own.

You can find the list of versions if you scroll down on the download page for the MS Word ALM Add-in
https://hpln.hpe.com/contentoffering/hp-alm-microsoft-word-add

Comment: Thanks for your response... It helped me on the correct route.
Not sure why, this new version 12.53 is not working! Tried with 12.01 and worked like charm